# Domain With Overbar

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-element-method

On page 8 of "A gentle introduction to the Finite Element Method" by Francisco–Javier Sayas, a space is defined on a domain omega with an overbar.

Previously he had used the omega domain to represent the physical domain.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what the overbar means?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xrGw.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overbar usually means 'closure', in some appropriate contextual sense. It's $\Omega \cup \{\text{something else}\}$ so that extra properties are satisfied. Very likely in this case it's for *completentess*, i.e. so that Cauchy sequences in $\overline{\Omega}$ converge in $\overline{\Omega}$ (though don't take my word for it).

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, it is the closure of $\Omega$:
\begin{equation}
\bar\Omega = \Omega \cup \Gamma
\end{equation}
in which $\Omega$ is the domain (a connected open set) and $\Gamma$ is the boundary of the problem.

The domain should generally be bounded, i.e. it can be enclosed by a circle with finite radius. That basically means that it is possible to "close" the open set by it's boundary.

As an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider the following case of a double barrier basket option:
\begin{equation}
\Omega = \{S \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a_1S_1 + a_2S_2>a_0 \ and \ b_1S_1 + b_2S_2<b_0  \} \\
\Gamma = \{S \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a_1S_1 + a_2S_2=a_0 \ or \ b_1S_1 + b_2S_2=b_0  \} \\
\bar\Omega = \Omega \cup \Gamma
\end{equation}
It is necessary to specify the boundary and the domain separately as the value of the option is only (strictly) positive in the domain and becomes zero on the boundary.